# JavaScript no startsWith in string?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Ok, so im trying to do str.startsWith but its saying its undefined.

```
getFilteredList: function() {
    var users = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
    var filteredList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var username = users[i].username;
        if (username.startsWith(username, Template.instance().filter.get())) {
            filteredList.push(users[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(filteredList);
    return filteredList;
}
```

Comment: Did you define a function called `startsWith`? You're not doing `str.startsWith(` in that snippet; you're doing `startsWith(str`.

Comment: Edited post, still doesn't work doing it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want:

```
username.startsWith(Template.instance().filter.get())
```

Correct syntax is:

> *string*.startsWith(*searchvalue*,*start*)

Comment: @CoderDayton You are passing username to startsWith again. :-/